# cant upload .htpasswd

Tags: .htaccess

G'Day Faulty Friends,

I just tried to upload .htaccess & .htpasswd to a clients server over FTP, and although the FTP process seems to go smoothly, refreshing the view shows that neither file are there.

the .htaccess file appears to be having an affect, as the desired password dialogue pops up, but the password fails to work

giving the password file a name > "a.htpasswd" > results in the file not disappearing, but upon reverting, it disappears.

Any clues? or is this one for Mr. Admin

-faithful Luser

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How are you checking? Linux normally hides files beginning with a period. Doing a `ls -a` will override the default and show them.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you put a period in front of a file the file is "hidden" in Linux.  That explains why .htaccess doesn't show up but a.htaccess does show up.

You can try this command to see if your file is there:

ls -la

You can also try and just edit the file like this:

vi .htaccess

See if it loads up. ;-)